# mysql query filter out NULL or blank rows

Tags: mysql, null, where-clause

I am a novice at writing sql, so thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide. 
I have a table (table1) in a mysql database that views like this:

```
+-----+----------+------------+
| id  | key      | value      |
+-----+----------+------------+
|   1 | name     | Bob        |
|   1 | location | ABC        |
|   1 | date     | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   2 | name     | Jim        |
|   2 | location | MID        |
|   2 | date     |            |
|   3 | name     |            |
|   3 | location |            |
|   3 | date     |            |
|   4 | name     | Sue        |
|   4 | location | DFW        |
|   4 | date     | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   5 | name     | Sue        |
|   5 | location |            |
|   5 | date     | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   6 | name     | Bob        |
|   6 | location | GRE        |
|   6 | date     | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   7 | name     |            |
|   7 | location |            |
|   7 | date     |            |
+-----+----------+------------+
```

I created a view where I basically invert (pivot) the rows to columns like this:

```
+-----+-------+----------+------------+
| id  | name  | location | date       |
+-----+-------+----------+------------+
|   1 | Bob   | ABC      | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   2 | Jim   | MID      |            |
|   3 |       |          |            |
|   4 | Sue   | DFW      | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   5 | Sue   |          | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   6 | Bob   | GRE      | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   7 |       |          |            |
|   8 | Bob   | DFW      | xxxx-xx-xx |
|   9 |       |          |            |
|  10 | Joe   | DFW      | xxxx-xx-xx |
|  11 |       |          |            |
|  12 |       |          |            |
|  13 |       |          |            |
|  14 | Jim   | SUS      | xxxx-xx-xx |
+-----+-------+----------+------------+
```

Here is the code for how I did this:

```
select c.`id`, max(ifnull(c.name,NULL)) as name, max(ifnull(c.location,NULL)) as location, max(ifnull(c.date,NULL)) as date from (
select `id`,
case when `key` = 'name' then value end as name,
case when `key` = 'location' then value end as location,
case when `key` = 'date' then value end as date
  from `table1`
  WHERE value != ''
) c group by `id`
```

I need to filter out the rows from the view where the name, location, and date are NULL or blank. I was able to clear about half of the rows by adding the `WHERE value != ''`, but how do I filter out the rest? `WHERE value IS NOT NULL` does not seem to help.

Comment: please format the question so we can read it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you use [`IFNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) the way that you do.
For example `max(ifnull(c.name,NULL))` is equivalent to `max(c.name)`.
But you can use it in a `HAVING` clause to filter out the *empty* rows:

```
select c.`id`, 
  max(c.name) as name, 
  max(c.location) as location, 
  max(c.date) as date 
from (
select `id`,
  case when `key` = 'name' then value end as name,
  case when `key` = 'location' then value end as location,
  case when `key` = 'date' then value end as date
  from `table1`
  WHERE value != ''
) c group by `id`
having ifnull(name, '') <> '' or ifnull(location, '') <> '' or ifnull(date, '') <> ''
```

If there is a case that name, location or date are not just empty strings but contain spaces then use also [`trim()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) like:

```
having ifnull(trim(name), '') <> '' or ifnull(trim(location), '') <> '' or ifnull(trim(date), '') <> ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have spaces as value? Try `WHERE TRIM(value) != ''` instead.

Try this?
`WHERE name != '' OR location != '' OR date != ''`

Comment: That gives me the same results as with WHERE value != ' '

Comment: I wonder if because there are other keys in the table attached to the id that have a value. If I could do the WHERE to only look for value != ' ' in name, location, & dates, would that fix it. I don't know how to write that, though. Any suggestions?